# Is it forbidden to try to give a specific description of HaShem?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology

Is it forbidden to try to give a definition of G-d as (i.e. a person/entity/consciousness who is unlimited without a physical shape not limited to space and time) ?

Comment: There is a sefer I believe called "shiur komo" I will try and find it. It describes HaShem in *extreme* physical detail. I believe the Rambam (or someone) once said about the sefer that it should be burned even on Yom Kippur that comes out on Shabbos.

Comment: @Yehoshua do you know who is the writer of the sefer ?

Comment: It's considered to be "ancient" -- from the "time of Chazal" of that means anything. This is considered a "fact". The Rambam mentions it in the hakdama to chelek (i.e. the place where he writes the 13 ikarim in mesectas Sanhedrin.) His comment about burning it is true, that which people add even on Yom Kippur that falls out on Shabbos (or perhaps what he wrote) is no doubt an exaggeration.

Comment: The Rambam also mentions it here in teshuvas (117): http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1730&st=&pgnum=215 ... The Right side is Judeo-Arabic, the left side is translated Hebrew so when you try and read teshuva 117 and go to the next page, keep in mind the Hebrew is on the left always. Unless you can read Judeo-Arabic ;)

Comment: @Yehoshua I don't speak Hebrew neither Judeo-Arabic, only Arabic, French and English (I am Lebanese) :P

Comment: We're going to have a real hard time then with some of these sources ;)....I wonder if there is anyone on this site who can even read the right side, so don't felt bad. If I'll give an answer to this question with the sources I will translate everything into English (when and if I have time.)

Comment: @Yehoshua Idolatry is (also) considered a fact by some; that doesn't make it true.

Comment: @mevaqesh what is your comment in connection to?

Comment: @Yehoshua "It's considered to be "ancient" -- from the "time of Chazal" of that means anything. This is considered a "fact"."

Comment: @mevaqesh .... True but there is evidence that the Rambam (although being against it clearly) used to help explain something once in Mishnah Torah and another place in his pirush on Mishnayos. It's not considered to be from a "non-kosher" source however the time is definitely from the period of Chazal. Seems to be only the Rambam spoke strongly against and maybe even he wasn't so much against it!

Comment: @Yehoshua Make up your mind: עַד מָתַי אַתֶּם פֹּסְחִים עַל שְׁתֵּי הַסְּעִפִּים אִם ה' הָאֱלֹקים לְכוּ אַחֲרָיו וְאִם הַבַּעַל לְכוּ אַחֲרָיו If you claim the Rambam held of it, you cant claim he wanted it burned. If you claim that he wanted it burned dont claim he supported it. Either way, dont say he was ambivalent. In reality, he originally thought it was an authentic text (which no doubt was interpreted far from its literal heresy) and later (as attested to by manuscripts of his own hand) forcefully rejected it. To say he was the only one who against it is misleading considering it...

Comment: @Yehoshua is an explicit text full of heresy. It is seven worse than the ubiquitous coprporealists who used to plague the Jews who believed vaguely that God was physical, in a very metaphysical, lofty, unimaginable sense. The shiur komah describes God in specific details. The fact that we dont find more rishonim discussing things like the length of God's nose does not mean that they all agreed to the Shiur Komah! If anything it implies the contrary. Either way, it should be noted that regardless of how it was historically interpreted, it is ridiculous to take it anywhere remotely near literaly

Comment: @Yehoshua and it therefeore contributes little to the conversation regarding the Jewish approach to understanding God. Incidentally, Ri Barceloni (author of _Sefer HaIttim_) who lived the century before the Rambam doubts its authenticity. Lastly it should be noted that even were one to prove its antiquity, that would not settle the dispute; it would take it right back to the time of the New Testament.

Comment: I'm impressed that your research took you so far as to know that the issue of this sefer and the Rambam's use had to do with the size of a nose. How did you know that? If you got that far then you might know more about the sefer than I anticipated anyone to know here (Does the sefer Shekiin from R' Saul Lieberman mean anything then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the shaar yichud ch.10 says it is impossible for us to grasp God as He is. so really He cannot be discussed in any kind of meaningful way. but we can know a bit about Him (for example that He possesses wisdom) by what He reveals to us on our level.

> Therefore, you should exert your mind until you know the Creator
>   through the evidences of His works and not strive to know Him in His
>   glorious essence. For He is exceedingly close to you from the side of
>   His deeds but infinitely remote in any representation of His essence
>   or comparison with it. As already stated, we will never be able to
>   find Him in this way. When you arrive at the stage where you abandon
>   (trying to find Him) through your thoughts and senses because He
>   cannot be grasped in this way, and you instead find Him in the
>   evidence of His deeds, as though He were inseparable from you - this
>   is the pinnacle of knowledge of Him which the prophet exhorts us on in
>   saying "Know therefore this day, and consider it in your heart, that
>   the L-ord He is G-d in heaven above, and upon the earth beneath: there
>   is none else" (Deut. 4:39).

another related quote (Daas Tevunos 40)

> "certainly G-d could have established the world through His omnipotent
>   system, in such a way that everything would be totally
>   incomprehensible to us, not before not after, without cause and
>   effect. If He had done so, no one would be able to open their mouths
>   for we would not be able to understand anything whatsoever... but
>   because He wanted us to understand a bit of His ways and attributes -
>   on the contrary He very much wants us to exert ourselves on this..."

Comment: You seem to be conflating a statement being meaningless and being forbidden. The OP asked about the latter.

Comment: @mevaqesh the OP accepting this answer indicates you are wrong

Answer (score 2):

[Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) famously adopts the approach of [negative-theology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides#Negative_theology) (see Rabbi Meir Triebitz's lengthy article about it [here](http://www.hashkafacircle.com/journal/R1_RT_Neg.pdf)). That is, Rambam opines that we cannot speak about God in terms of what he (it) *is*, but rather what he (it) *is not*. That is, we can speak of God not being corporeal, not being limited, etc.

Also noteworthy, is the Gemara Megillah 18a

> אסור לספר בשבחו של הקב''ה דא''ר אלעזר מאי דכתיב {תהילים קו-ב} מי ימלל גבורות ה' ישמיע כל תהלתו למי נאה למלל גבורות ה' למי שיכול להשמיע כל תהלתו אמר רבה בר בר חנה א''ר יוחנן המספר בשבחו של הקב''ה יותר מדאי נעקר מן העולם שנאמר {איוב לז-כ} היסופר לו כי אדבר אם אמר איש כי יבלע דרש ר' יהודה איש כפר גבוריא ואמרי לה איש כפר גבור חיל מאי דכתיב {תהילים סה-ב} לך דומיה תהלה סמא דכולה משתוקא

To summarize: one should avoid praising God [the commentators strongly limit this statement. Don't get the impression that one should actually not praise God. Rashi for example limits this to establishing new blessings] since in so doing he implies that this is the extent of God's praise.

IIRC [R. Yoseph Chaim of Baghdad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Hayyim) limits this to  praise of God's nature [discouraged under certain circumstances] and praise of his acts [always encouraged] in his "B'nayahu commentary thereon. For somewhat similar sentiments expressed in his "Ben Yehoyada" commentary, see [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_20203_33.pdf#xml=http://www.hebrewbooks.org/hilite.aspx?pgnum=33&hilite=2b2bf500-05f6-41a6-83ad-3c080232bd48&toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&view=FitH).

Answer (score -1):

The *Rambam* seems to hold it's permitted to "give a definition of G-d": consider that he spends much of chapter 1 of *Y'sode Hatora* doing so.

Comment: .. and starts the Moreh proving that all we can know about G-d is (1) what He isn't, and (2) how His actions appear to us. And yet closes the Moreh with chapters explaining how the ultimate human perfection, the key to prophecy, receiving personal Divine Providence (hashgachah peratis), and olam haba, as being a consequence of knowing about G-d.

Comment: the rambam seems to be listing what God is not. whereas a definition is a description of what something is.

Comment: @ray, `m-w.com` (the Web version of _Webster's Third New International Dictionary_, a well-respected dictionary) gives "an untrue statement" and "the quality of not being true or accurate" as its definitions of _falsehood_. Apparently, a definition can be in terms of what something is not. More to the point, the asker here, when asking whether it's permitted to define God, gave specific examples of definition in terms of what He's not ("...who is unlimited without a physical shape not limited to space and time"); so obviously he's satisfied with such a definition.

Comment: @msh210 i see. i was coming from how chazal understand the word definition (geder). Marpe Lenefesh on shaar yichud ch1: the meaning of the word "definition" is: "a correct and complete teaching on the thing that one wishes to explain what it is". Therefore one must call it with a name which is specific to it, so that the reader does not err that one's intent was for something else... for example, if we define a human being as a "speaking being" - this is a comprehensive teaching without breaches, but if you define him as an "alive being"

Comment: this is not a complete definition, and there is a breach in your words since animals are also called "alive".

Comment: @ray, so this is a new objection, I guess. Earlier you objected to the definition's being negative rather than positive; now you object to its being incomprehensive (in the sense that it applies to more than just the thing being defined). (That's fine; I just want to be clear.) I don't think it's incomprehensive: he says He's "ממציא כל נמצא" and so on: it doesn't seem possible that that applies to more than one being.

Comment: right, more correct to say negations than assertions. mamtzi doesnt say anything about His essence. just what He does.

Comment: @ray, so this is a new objection, I guess. Earlier you objected to the definition's being incomprehensive (in the sense that it applies to more than just Him); now you object to its describing what He does rather than His essence. (That's fine; I just want to be clear.) While I grant you that the asker, above, uses examples of essence rather than action, I have no reason to think that that was exclusive; more to the point, even though the example I gave in my earlier comment was "ממציא", the _Rambam_ says things unrelated to His actions also, like "מצוי ראשון" and "שאין לו קץ ותכלית".

Comment: i hear. from what i read in the shaar yichud, we have no understanding whatsoever as to what it means to be an eternal or infinite being. these are just to negate the opposite. i assume the rambam means the same

Comment: @ray, so this is a new objection, I guess. Earlier you objected to the definition's describing what He does rather than His essence; now you object to its being negative rather than positive. (That's fine; I just want to be clear.) I already dealt with the negative-rather-than-positive objection, above.

Comment: its all one objection. the rambam is not defining God.